# No columns when binding anonymous list to DataSource of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource, anonymous-types

I'm trying to bind a list of anonymous type to a DataGridView, but Columns and Rows seems to be empty.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var view = new DataGridView() { DataSource = new[] { new { Foo = 1, Bar = "2" } }};

    Assert.AreEqual(2, view.Columns.Count); // fail, count = 0
    Assert.AreEqual(1, view.Rows.Count); // fail, count = 0
}
```

I don't find many resources on accessing Columns and Rows after a Binding of anonymous type. Any ideas of why such a comportement?

Edit :

Set the parent to a mock Form, and here you go:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var view = new DataGridView() { Parent = new Form() , DataSource = new[] { new { Foo = 1, Bar = "2" } }};
    Assert.AreEqual(2, view.Columns.Count); // win
    Assert.AreEqual(1, view.Rows.Count); // win
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling your `TestMethod1` in `Load` event handler:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   TestMethod1();
}
```

Also remember that your grid does not have any parent so how it is rendered? So try assign some Parent for it:

```
var view = new DataGridView(){Parent = this};
//...
```

The reason is your `DataGridView` is not rendered at the very beginning before the UI is loaded.

Comment: That's work if I add the DataGridView in a Form. But I doesn't need or want to add the DataGridView to a form. What make the list of Columns and Rows to be set?

Comment: @CyrilGandon you can't, as I said, if it doesn't have parent, it's not rendered and the columns and rows are rendered only when the grid has parent. When they are not rendered, the columns and rows have no information. You should use some `DataTable` instead if you don't want to show your *grid/table*. Setting some data for the grid without showing it **doesn't make** sense.

Comment: Wow, that was the point. `var view = new DataGridView() { Parent = new Form() };` works!